# Does Excel have Find & Replace match placeholder?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to use wildcards in Excel Find & Replace dialog, to replace cells with a pattern match. Made up example column:

```
_4
_44
_13
...
```

I want to replace these values with:

```
(4)
(44)
(13)
...
```

So I tried with `_*` which finds the pattern succesfully, but I couldn't find anywhere if Excel features match placeholder. For example with regex I would have used brackets and `\1` as match placeholder. Does Excel have this feature at all?

Comment: I don't believe so; however, you can use regex in VBA. It's not nearly as easy as a Search and Replace dialog, but it will work if you need to use regex.

Comment: As a workaround you could use LibreOffice which does support regular expressions including capture groups in Search/Replace.
Here is a [list of all supported constructs](https://help.libreoffice.org/5.0/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions). It includes `()` in search strings to capture a part of the match and `$1` in replacement strings to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Excel's pattern matching capabilities are extremely limited: literal characters, * to match any number of unspecified characters, and ? to match a single unspecified character. There is no native match placeholder capability, either in worksheet functions or in VBA.

However, as Excellll noted, you can use regex in VBA, and can develop user-defined functions that are regex-based.

To access regex in your code, add a reference to the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5" library via the `Tools`->`References` selections in the main menu for the Visual Basic code editor.

I have not found any comprehensive documentation for the library, but you can find a lot of bits and pieces - and example code - with a Google search.

Comment: This article https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f makes it seem like there are placeholder capabilities in Office, but I can't seem to get it to work in Excel so it may be Word only?

Comment: @imotama Word 2013 has the "Advanced Find" dialog but Excel 2013 does not. (C'mon MS, don't force me to use VBA just to search my spreadsheet with regex!)

Comment: Here's a worksheet function implementing this: https://gist.github.com/JohnLBevan/833509322f3b6fe66bcbe6b5a377ab48.  More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/361842

Answer (score 3):

Though this is a very late answer, I have had success with an add-in called *RegEx Find/Replace* to do exactly what you want.  But I do not know of any built-in capability for this in Excel.

The add-in creates a button on the ribbon which launches a dialog box that looks very much like the Excel Find/Replace.  Most of it works the same as well - you can search within a sheet or workbook, by columns or rows, match case, etc.  (There is no format matching, though.)

Note, however, that the add-in uses regular expressions as implemented in VBScript and so works differently than the standard Excel Find/Replace.  For example, your search string `_*` would not work.  It matches any cell with zero or more underscores, which is anything.  For your example, I had success finding `_(\d+)` and replacing with `'($1)`.  (The apostrophe is just to prevent Excel from interpreting `(4)` as a negative value.)

I am in no way affiliated with the website or developer - just found it through a web search.  Also, I use Excel 2007 and cannot say whether this still works in later versions.  I have used it successfully in both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

The *RegEx Find/Replace* add-in can be found at http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to include a short example of how to use the software you recommend?

Comment: Confirmed: I have used this and it works.

Comment: Warning: this add-on doesn't appear to register its replacements in the undo history.

Comment: I can confirm the warning from @Ruslan.  Changes are not available for undo, and in fact the undo stack is cleared.  However, the add-in does prompt to save the file before making changes.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the extension of the file from .xlsx to .zip
Unzip the whole lot
Locate the sheets in the subfolder \xl\worksheets
Open the file in emacs (or any other txt editor with sufficient power)
Change your stuff
Rezip, rename from .zip to .xlsx
Note: Excel keeps an internal list of computational dependencies, so if your changes involve references to other cells in some kind, recomputation will not happen. I solved this by a two step approach, the second step using excel's replace function which will trigger a correct internal update.
Sounds complicated but is actually a 5 min procedure!

Comment: I used this technique and it worked well. You need to be comfortable editing XML with a text editor, and also working with zip files. But if you're determined to use regex, this may describe you anyway. Quick tip: you can force recalculate the entire workbook with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F9`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to copy the sheet to a table in Word, do the find and replace, then copy it back to Excel.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you described how to do what you suggest.  *How* would you change `_357` to `(357)`?  (I realize that the other answers to this question are also lacking in specific instructions, and they could all be improved.  I invite you to rise to a higher standard of quality.)