# Find and replace numbers in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace, wildcards

I have a spreadsheet with @ 4000 cells containing a summation like (for example) `=439+23+678+1` (Stock market data.) Each number in the formula could vary between 1 and 5 digits. I need to replace each cell with a summation of only the first two numbers.

A Find and Replace operation would be perfect, but wildcard characters don't work for numbers. I know there is probably some complicated VBA instruction that would work, but I'm VBA illiterate, so if anyone can help on that front, please don't assume any prior knowledge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Excel have Find & Replace match placeholder?](https://superuser.com/questions/630692/does-excel-have-find-replace-match-placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

When you say wildcards don't work for numbers, what do you mean? Do you have Use Wildcards selected? Does each cell have the same number of fields? If so, you should be able to search for this:

```
(=<*>+<*>)+<*>+<*>
```

If not, and there are no decimals, you could search for this:

```
(=[0-9]{1,}+[0-9]{1,})+<*>
```

In both cases, replace with `\1`

You might have to switch to Formula View first using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) if you haven't already.

Comment: That functionality does not work in Excel so far (2019).