# How to concatenate a string to all cells of a column (in-place)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to simply append some text to all cells of a column, but I would like to do it in-place. i.e. update the same column with the new values.

For example, if I have a column:

| A |
| --- |
| a |
| b |

I want to get:

| A |
| --- |
| a new |
| b new |

I know I can do `=A1&" new"` on the first cell of B and drag (then override column A with the generated values in column B). But as I said, I'm looking for an ***in-place*** solution that doesn't use an auxiliary column and simply updates column A.

Preferably looking for a solution without VBA, but that would be accepted as well.

Comment: Since you didn't say what it's for, you may be satisfied with this solution: select the entire column and give it a format like `@" new"`

Comment: @JohnSUN That's interesting. But as I understand it this is just a display thing right? Is there a way to use this to actually make this the new value of the cell?

Comment: Just select column and use **Ctrl+H**: find "asterisk" `*`, replace with "asterisk text" `* new` for whole cell *(Sorry for the delay in answering - due to the shelling of russian terrorists, there was no electricity and the Internet)*

Comment: @JohnSUN That is more than understandable. I thought about doing something like that, but that just gives me literal `* new` in the cell. I am a bit familiar with regex and thought about doing a group replacement, something like find `(*)` and replace `\1 new` but don't know if that's possible

Comment: Do you check option [**Match entire cell contents**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-0e304ca5-ecef-4808-b90f-fdb42f892e90)? (They say *You can use wildcard characters — question mark (?), asterisk (* * *), tilde (~) — in your search criteria* - as you can see it's not about regular expressions)

Comment: @JohnSUN Yes the search function works. i.e. using `*` in the Find finds everything. But then I don't know what to replace it with. As I said, using `*` in the Replace field gives the literal asterisk `*`

Comment: @JohnSUN [It seems this is not possible](https://superuser.com/a/632573/1757157)

Comment: I think the Custom format is the best way.

Comment: @Lee care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to create a new column with your
formula `=A1&" new"` and copy-paste it over the old column.
You may use Paste special of Values to not overwrite formulas.

The complex solution would be to use a VBA macro like this :

```
Sub AppendToExistingOnLeft()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Selection
  If c.Value <> "" Then c.Value = c.Value & " new"
Next
End Sub
```

This VBA can be used like this :

1. Select the range
2. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open a
   Microsoft Visual Basic window.
3. Click *Insert > Module* and paste the above VBA code in the Module window
4. Press F5 key to run this macro.

Comment: Thank you the VBA solution does work well for what I wanted. I would have preferred non-VBA solution so not accepting just yet but that does indeed what I wanted. Thank you